# MySQL Trigger - INSERT on condition of UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I'm trying to find the most effecient way of inserting data into another table when a particular field is updated on trigger table. The INSERT should only occur on a specific type of update.

The table on which I want to create the trigger is named **incremental**. The table I'm inserting into is named **crm_record**

On incremental there is a field called status. By default when a record is initially added to the table the status field is set to new. After billing has processed that value changes to processed. So once this occurs I want to INSERT into crm_record, only if the value of another field (success) is set to 1.

I have considered using both CASE and IF but would like an expert's opinion on the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger and test the value of `status` and `success` together. If it's going only going to be one state you're testing for then an `IF` statement would be the simplest way to go about it.

However before implementing a trigger it's always worth going back a step and checking to see if the row in `crm_record` shouldn't actually be inserted via the code logic when the `status` and `success` columns are updated.

Comment: Thanks Ira, I will write up the code and post back here with my results

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I eventually went with this that seemed to work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

```
CREATE TRIGGER `incremental5_after_ins_tr_crmm` AFTER UPDATE ON `incremental5`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF Status = 'processed' AND Success = 1 THEN
INSERT INTO crm_master (msisdn,source,contract_type,revenue) VALUE    (new.msisdn,'INC5',new.contract_type,revenue=revenue+2.5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE contract_type=new.contract_type,revenue=revenue+2.5;
END IF;
END;
```